# Apache redirect using RewriteEngine with and without query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm trying to get 2 redirections set on my htaccess file but I can't make it to work.

The desired output is:

- if the user goes to `www.mywebsite.com/page1`, it gets redirected to `/folder/newPage`
- if the user goes to `www.mywebsite.com/page1?a=123`, it gets redirected to `/folder/anotherPage?a=123`

I tried this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/page1$ /folder/newPage [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/page1(.*)$ /folder/anotherPage$1 [R=301,L]
```

I also tried something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/page1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/newPage [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/page1$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/anotherPage%1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that Rewrite mod is turned on on my apache.

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Check through the following:

1. `RewriteEngine On` is present before all the rules
2. `AllowOverride` directive allows your htaccess files to load
3. htaccess receives URLs without the leading slashes, unlike server config files, or VHosts file.
4. `.*` matches **0 or more** characters, thus `%{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$` also matches empty query strings. Change this to `.+`.

Final rules should be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^page1$ /folder/newPage [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^page1$ /folder/anotherPage?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` is set at the beginning of the file. Rewrite mod is ON and working fine. About 3. not sure how to verify this?

Comment: @alexmngn Change `RewriteRule ^/page1$` to `RewriteRule ^page1$`

Comment: I got the 1st one to work, but not the second one... Seems like the first rule takes over the 2nd rule

Comment: @alexmngn I've updated the reply above. You may also try using `R=302` instead of `301`. Or you might've to clear the browser's cache, to actually see updated rules in effect.

Comment: Can't make your rules to work... 

This one works: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/page1/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/newPage [R=301,L]` but also redirects to this page when there is a query param

Comment: Yes the cache is clean